# ExpressMapper tutorial assumptions -- I don’t know where to start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, express-mapper

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5
- EF 6

In all honesty, I have never made use of a mapper before, and while the [ExpressMapper tutorial](http://www.expressmapper.org/) bounces across the high-altitude highlights, it makes several assumptions about knowledge that I don’t have.

So in no general order:

The product is supposed to have all its code centralized in one spot. Where is this spot? Where do I put it? The examples start out with,

```
public void MappingRegistration() {
    Mapper.Register<Product,ProductViewModel>();
}
```

But I don’t know where to put this. Does it go into its own file or is it in another file, such as within App_Start?

If it is elsewhere in the project, do I create it under its own namespace?

If I have a viewModel that is filled in a different way than its dataModel is filled, how do I handle each type separately? As in, the data is pulled out of the DB and fills the viewModel with completely different conditional rules than how the data is pulled from the viewModel and inserted into or updated back to the database.

How do I bring in external conditionals that affect how the data and which data is inserted into the DB, such as the Role of the user, their UserId and UserName, and various project Settings? Depending on conditionals, some entries may end up with a null value instead of an actual value. How can I do business logic validation using these conditionals (User is actually updating his own record, by comparing their session UserId with the UserId stored in the DB)?

Right now I am doing a lot of manual mapping in the Models but this is problematic especially since the method I am using (to cut down on code in the controller) means that during an update I cannot examine an entry in the DB prior to updating it in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can stick it anywhere you want - the only thing necessary is that it gets called in code, before you call `Mapper.Map<Product,ProductViewModel>`.

E.g.

```
public static void main()
{
    Mapper.Register<Product,ProductViewModel>();
}
```

is functionally the same as

```
public static void main()
{
    RegisterMapping();
}

public static void RegisterMapping()
{
    Mapper.Register<Product,ProductViewModel>();
}
```

If you want to map one class member to another class member with a different name, you can specify it with `Member` mapping.

```
Mapper.Register<Product, ProductViewModel>()
    .Member(dest => dest.efgh, src => src.abcd);
```

If you want to apply special conversion rules, you can specify that with a `Function` mapping - e.g. you want the price in the ProductViewModel to be 2x the price of the product :

```
Mapper.Register<Product, ProductViewModel>()
    .Function(dest => dest.Price, src => src.Price*2);
```

Any customisation that you make to the mapping should be done at the time you register the mapping, and has to be done on a Member-by-Member basis AFAIK.

If there's anything else specific that you need help with, leave a comment.